# Sync Opera Mobile with Google Chrome for Mac

Tags: google-chrome, android, opera

I use Google Chrome on the Mac as my daily browser.

Is there any way to automatically sync Android Opera with Google Chrome for Mac like Chrome for Android with desktop Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Opera Link is a closed protocol, Opera only synchronizes through that, and Chrome uses another protocol. So no, you can't synchronize them.</strike>

(And this is the browser war, therefore I think it won't happen. Ever.)

EDIT:
Sorry, it looks like I had some outdated information. It looks like the thing is possible, but I still can't really see Opera fanboys developing extensions for Chrome.

It's not really synchronization but you can access your Opera Mobile stuff on the web with Chrome too. You just have to go to the https://my.opera.com/%username%/account/link/ page.

Comment: You're wrong: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-opera-link-api/